# Vector spaces "over" a topological space

Tags: general-topology, category-theory, differential-topology, vector-bundles, topological-vector-spaces

The definition of a vector bundle includes a map $\pi : E \rightarrow X$ and an assignment to each $x \in X$ a vector space structure on $\pi^{-1}(x)$. However, I find this viewpoint a little strange and hard to work with. So, I was just wondering if we can recast this in slightly different terms.

Given a commutative ring object $R$ in the category $\mathbf{Top}$, it seems to me that we can get a corresponding commutative ring object $R$ in the slice category $\mathbf{Top}/X$, namely $(X \times R, (x,r) \mapsto x).$ My idea was then to study $R$-module objects in the category $\mathbf{Top}/X$, and with a bit of luck, these will turn out to be the same as maps $E \rightarrow X$ that are equipped with $R$-module structures on each fiber.

> **Question.** Does this work, and if not, what goes wrong?
>
> Also, is there a slick way of expressing the local triviality condition in this framework, so as to recover the usual definition of a vector bundle?

Comment: Remark: I think diff geometers, category theorists etc. chose the wrong conventions regarding "over" and "under." If we think of categories as generalized preordered sets, then $e \lesssim x$ categorifies to $E \rightarrow X$. The space $E$ isn't "over" $X$, it's under. Sigh. What can one man do against such reckless hate? LoTR-themed rambling ensues...

Comment: I think that you use the wrong convention. ;-)

Comment: @HeinrichD, what do you mean?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covering_space#/media/File:Covering_space_diagram.svg

Comment: @HeinrichD, but that's under... the domain of the morphism is the "lower" side, irrespective of how it's drawn on paper.

Comment: I don't understand why you think like that. Maybe it helps to imagine the covering space as a real-life object, and the projection as the shadow cast by the sun, which hits on the ground, which is *below*. And it is not good to view categories as generalized preordered sets. Think of the category of sets, do you really see a map $X \longrightarrow Y$ as a sort of statement that $X$ is lower than $Y$?

Comment: @HeinrichD well a map $X \rightarrow Y$ is a machine that turns proofs that $X$ is inhabited into proofs that $Y$ is inhabited. So yeah, I kind of do. Of course, the mere existence of a machine that turns proofs that $X$ is inhabited into proofs that $Y$ is inhabited isn't too interesting; it's the whole space of such machines where all the action happens.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, and this is probably the best framework for a conceptual definition of vector bundles, because you can prove many basic results about vector bundles just by proving them for $R$-modules in a general categorical setting (i.e. if $R$ is a ring object in a cartesian category). Unfortunately you cannot find it in most introductory texts.

Notice that an $R_X := (X \times R \to X)$-module object in $\mathbf{Top}/X$ is not just a map $E \to X$ with topological $R$-module structures on the fibers, but they should "vary continuously over $X$". To be precise, one requires that scalar multiplication $R \times E  = R_X \times_X E \to E$ and addition $E \times_X E \to E$ are continuous.

The category of $R_X$-modules is additive. Finite coproducts and products coincide, and are given by fiber products over $X$. Notice that $R_X$ can be regarded as an $R_X$-module. Hence, also $R_X^n = R^n \times X$ can be regarded as an $R_X$-module. Let us call an $R_X$-module **finite free** if it is isomorphic to $R_X^n$ for some $n$.

It is clear that every map $X \to Y$ induces a **pullback functor** from $R_Y$-modules to $R_X$-modules. If $X \to Y$ is the inclusion of a subspace, then this will be simply called restriction.

**Definition.** An **$R$-module bundle over $X$** is an $R_X$-module $E$ for which there exists an open covering $\{X_i \to X\}$ such that $E|_{X_i}$ is finite free. If $R$ is a field, we speak of **$R$-vector bundles** as usual.

Notice that the same defintion works verbatim for a) the category of manifolds, and b) the category of schemes (usually with $R=\mathbb{A}^1$). For schemes the "fiberwise" definition does not work anyway.

Comment: Great answer. Could you also provide some references for the details?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that this is somewhere in SGA, but I am too lazy right now. Please ask specific questions if you like, I will try to answer them.